# Chronologically sorting date time (YYYY-MM-DD) series with precision down to the level of day

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, series, rank

I have a pandas datetime series column (in string format) that I would like to have chronologically-sorted. Since the original series are already converted to the YYYY-MM-DD timestamp format like the following:

```
0     1993-03-25
1     1985-06-18
2     1971-07-08
3     1975-09-27
4     2000-02-06
5     1979-07-06
6     1978-05-18
7     1989-10-24
8     1989-10-24
9     1971-04-10
10    1985-05-11
11    2011-04-09
12    1998-08-01
13    1972-01-26
14    1990-05-24
```

Note: it's only a small fraction of the data, it's for illustration purpose

I want to sort them by chronological order down to the precision of 'day' (year --> month --> day) and rank them by their indices in the original series where new index column is on the left and the original (sorted) indices for each datetime string are on the right based on their chronological ranking:

```
0     10
1     7
2     1
3     3
4     12
5     5
6     4
7     8
8     8
9     0
10    6
11    13
12    11
13    2
14    9
```

However, note that there are instances where datetime strings are tied, for example, `df[7]` and `df[8]` are the same day, and thus getting the same rank `8`.

I have used methods like `.rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)` and `.sort_values(kind='mergesort')` to sort this datetime series by the sequence of year-month-day, but can't seem to get rid of the 'tied' issue.

Are there better approaches to tackle this tied rank issue and get the output I want?

Thank you.

New Edit

I used the following code to generate the df, the .txt file contains a large number of unorganized text string from which I extracted datetime elements using re.findall(r' ') function.

```css
import pandas as pd
import re  
import datetime

#load text string
doc = []
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        doc.append(line)

df = pd.Series(doc)

# extract datetimes from different datetime patterns, the extracted datetime elements are in string format contained in list [] object

df['date'] = df.str.findall(r'\b....\b')

# manually replace some irregular patterns/expressions
df['date'].iloc[...] = ['10/21/79']
df['date'].iloc[...] = ['7/11/2000']
            ...
df['date'].drop('date', inplace=True)

# convert list object in each cell to string
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))

# convert to datetime format and check for NaT cell.
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))
```

The output in each cell of this series is in the form YYYY-MM-DD and dtype =  timestamp.

Comment: Are your dates actually datetimes, or are they strings that are in a nice format?

Comment: They are string. I will edit this information on the thread.

Comment: If they're in YYYY-MM-DD, can't you just sort lexographically?

Comment: How can I sort them lexicographically? It will be really appreciated if someone could enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column with the dates as a datetime object and then sort by that.

```
In [103]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('t.csv', header=0, sep='\s+', index_col='id')

In [105]: df['date2'] = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')

In [106]: df.sort_values('date2')

Out[106]: 
          date      date2
id                       
9   1971-04-10 1971-04-10
2   1971-07-08 1971-07-08
13  1972-01-26 1972-01-26
3   1975-09-27 1975-09-27
6   1978-05-18 1978-05-18
5   1979-07-06 1979-07-06
10  1985-05-11 1985-05-11
1   1985-06-18 1985-06-18
7   1989-10-24 1989-10-24
8   1989-10-24 1989-10-24
14  1990-05-24 1990-05-24
0   1993-03-25 1993-03-25
12  1998-08-01 1998-08-01
4   2000-02-06 2000-02-06
11  2011-04-09 2011-04-09
```

And if you want to add the ranking column:

```
In [112]: df['sorting'] = df.sort_values('date2').index

In [113]: df.sorting
Out[113]: 
id
0      9
1      2
2     13
3      3
4      6
5      5
6     10
7      1
8      7
9      8
10    14
11     0
12    12
13     4
14    11
Name: sorting, dtype: int64
```

Since your csv doesn't actually have a header row like I added, do this:

```
In [132]: df=pd.DataFrame.from_csv('t.csv', header=None, sep='\s+')
In [133]: df[2] = df[1].astype('datetime64[ns]')
In [134]: df[3] = df.sort_values(2).index
In [135]: df[3]
Out[135]: 
0
0      9
1      2
2     13
3      3
4      6
5      5
6     10
7      1
8      7
9      8
10    14
11     0
12    12
13     4
14    11
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

OK, assuming they're already Timestamp objects or whatever as defined in the last line of the provided code, you can just sort them as they are:

```
In [194]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('dates.txt', sep='\s+')

In [195]: df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'
     ...: ))

In [196]: df['sorting'] = df['date'].sort_values().index

In [197]: df
Out[197]: 
         date  sorting
id                    
0  1993-03-25        9
1  1985-06-18        2
2  1971-07-08       13
3  1975-09-27        3
4  2000-02-06        6
5  1979-07-06        5
6  1978-05-18       10
7  1989-10-24        1
8  1989-10-24        7
9  1971-04-10        8
10 1985-05-11       14
11 2011-04-09        0
12 1998-08-01       12
13 1972-01-26        4
14 1990-05-24       11
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It gives an error message saying the command line 'df['date2'] = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')' can only join an iterable

Comment: Does your CSV look exactly like the data you provided in your post?

Comment: Yes, they are created using 'pd.to_datetime()'

Comment: OK, I added an example to the end of my post without headers that works for me.

Comment: Hi, this syntax "df[1]astype('datetime64[ns]')" doesn't work with my editor. I suspect this is because my pandas Series is named df['date'] (but it doesn't have a header just like the one you used), putting astype('datetime64[ns]') after it generated an error.

Comment: Oops. put a `.` before `astype`. That was a typo(updating post)

Comment: If that doesn't work, A) follow the steps I provided exactly; B) post the code you're using to generate your DF

Comment: Code added as edit on the bottom of the thread. Thanks so much for taking a look at it.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code? As in something I can copy and paste into my shell and run. Your code gives me a lot of errors, syntax and otherwise, as it is. StackOverflow has a guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am trying to think of a way to do a reproducible code as StackOverflow wouldn't allow me to post original txt file, the big chuck of parsing and cleaning steps in the code block are probably meaningless. The only thing matters is the output, its a pandas Series named df['date'] containing rows of date time string in the form of YYYY-MM-DD as seen in the first code block of my post.

Comment: If that's the case then I don't see why it won't work as I've shown. I copied your data into a text file and did the exact steps I've shown. Are you sure your column is of `str` type?

Comment: Sorry I probably got it wrong, they are timestamp (pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp) I apologize.

Comment: OK, I've applied the `pd.to_datetime` function as you have to all of the columns and provided another example. Last one, as I have to work :)

Comment: Thanks again! I will give it a try and also edit the 'timestamp' issue in my original thread to see if others would like to join in and share their two-cent.

Comment: It's the same as '.sort_values(kind='mergesort')' that I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: It can't possibly be. The indexes are unique in my method, whereas you get duplicate "tied" ranks the mergesort way.

Comment: Ok, I will do some manually inspection later. Certainly not trying to defend the mergesort method (it's obviously not suitable for my purpose here), just really want to know the difference between the two.

Comment: I just tested both methods and they actually do give me the same exact result. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I also found out that I have many duplicates and triplets of the same datetime in my file, this might be the root cause of ranking problem though it won't be reflected in '.index'. I need to find a method that gives lower rank to whichever duplicated rows that appear first in the column. For that, I will open a new question thread as Stackoverflow is curing me for using this as chatroom. Again, your answer (and obvious patience for clarifying this) should receive full credit!

Comment: Oh, for that you may need to write something from scratch. Glad I was able to help a little. :)